# Trying to get a magnetic field behave like a quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator

**Background:**

Let’s take a magnetic vector potential $\vec{A} = (A_1(x_1,x_2),A_2(x_1,x_2),0)^T$, s.t. $\vec{B}=(0,0,B)^T$, the Hamiltonian in the position representation can be rewritten as:

$$
H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial_{x_3}^2+H_{\perp}
$$

with

$$
H_{\perp} = \frac{1}{2m}[\frac{\hbar}{i}(\hat{x}_1\partial_{x_1}+ \hat{x}_2\partial_{x_1})-\frac{q}{c}A_{\perp}]
$$

We can further rewrite this as:

$$
H_{\perp}=\frac{qB}{2mc}[\pi_1^2+\pi_2^2]
$$

with $\pi_j=\sqrt{\frac{c}{qB}}(\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{x_j}-\frac{q}{c}A_j)$

**Question:**

I‘m now trying to define ladder operators $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\hbar}}(\pi_1+i\pi_2)$, analogous to the quantum harmonic oscillator. But for this to work I‘d need:

$$
[\pi_1,\pi_2]=i\hbar
$$

But $[\pi_1,\pi_2]=\frac{i \hbar}{B}([\partial_{x_1},A_2]-[\partial_{x_2},A_1])=\frac{i \hbar}{B}(\nabla \times \vec{A}-A_2 \partial_{x_1}+A_1 \partial_{x_2})$

My question is, what do I do with this $-A_2 \partial_{x_1}+A_1 \partial_{x_2}$, which would need to vanish for this to work, but clearly $(-A_2 \partial_{x_1}+A_1 \partial_{x_2})f(x_1,x_2)\neq 0 $ in general.
Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: I think Landau's quantization is what you're looking for (cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization).